# How should we tag Sakurasou no Pet na Kanojo?

Tags: discussion, tags

[Sakurasou no Pet na Kanojo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pet_Girl_of_Sakurasou) is an LN with a recent anime adaptation. The tag [sakurasou-no-pet-na-kanojo](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sakurasou-no-pet-na-kanojo) is 26 characters, which just barely doesn't fit, so the user who created it [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4482/why-is-maid-chan-voice-actor-listed-as-in-ending-credits) used [sakurasou-no-pet](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sakurasou-no-pet) instead. This is a reasonable choice, but not necessarily the best one. There is an English name, "The Pet Girl of Sakurasou", which would fit at 25 characters if we used [the-pet-girl-of-sakurasou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-pet-girl-of-sakurasou). Personally I've not heard the English title used much.

**What tag should we use for this series?**

Comment: I came here to suggest the english name.. it fits within SE's restrictions and _is_ valid. So I say use it.

Comment: @iKlsR That's a reasonable suggestion, but it should probably be an answer so that people can vote on it.

Answer (score 4):

The english tag name [the-pet-girl-of-sakurasou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-pet-girl-of-sakurasou) works as it is valid, legible and is nested within SE's tag naming restrictions so I say use it instead.

On your comment about the popularity of the english title, "sakurasou" is present in both so it should be found quite easily.

Comment: +1, though still waiting to hear other opinions. Two of the three keywords in the two titles are the same, namely Sakurasou and Pet. Kanojo vs Girl are different, but it shouldn't hurt too much w.r.t. search traffic since both are common words in their respective languages anyway. We do also tend to prefer the English titles, at least when they're popular or recognizable.

Comment: Also, people are probably going to type "Sakurasou" first and the autocompletion should show the corresponding tag. For now I'll just edit both of my questions for that tag to use [tag:the-pet-girl-of-sakurasou] tag.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use [sakurasou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sakurasou) and note its full name in the description? Alternatives can be added as synonyms.

Comment: I like this idea. This tag looks very nice compared to parts of the full name.