# How should we tag Denpa Onna to Seishun Otoko?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Related to [How should we tag Sakurasou no Pet na Kanojo?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/646/how-should-we-tag-sakurasou-no-pet-na-kanojo)

I've searched on some sites that follow anime and manga to see if the Japanese have a shortened name for it, but so far nothing came up. Since I needed to tag a question and it was late at night I settled on Denpa-Onna, but there are a few other works that have that in their name.

Comment: Which other works have Denpa Onna as their title?

Answer (score 3):

The generic advice for how to name series tags is [here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/521/24) but most of those do not apply for this series.

Neither the English name "Ground Control to Psychoelectric Girl" nor the Japanese title "Denpa Onna to Seishun Otoko" fits without cutting something out. The English name would need to be trimmed to just [psychoelectric-girl](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychoelectric-girl), which is probably not the best option. I tried a [Google battle](http://www.googlebattle.com/?domain=%22denpa+onna%22&domain2=%22psychoelectric+girl%22&submit=Go%21) and "Denpa Onna" is 20 times as common as "Psychoelectric Girl", which I think is the sort of extreme case in which we should be using the Japanese name. Personally, I'd never even heard of the English name before looking for it.

I think the best option is probably [denpa-onna-seishun-otoko](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denpa-onna-seishun-otoko) which fits at 24 characters. We cut out the "to", in Japanese means "and", so there's basically no loss of information and all the keywords are present.

Comment: +1 for this.. [denpa-onna] is also viable as it is the shortened name the wiki uses.

Comment: [denpa-onna] is another valid choice. I slightly prefer the longer tag as it has all the keywords, but IMO it's not going to make a significant difference either way.

Comment: Since a week has gone by, and no one else seems to have an opinion on this matter, I retagged the question according to this answer ([tag:denpa-onna-seishun-otoko] is now the tag in use).